# Apply Twitter Bootstrap LESS to my own .less stylesheet not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

In Twitter Bootstrap v. 2.3.2 `navbar.less` file, you can find this code:

```
// Active nav items
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: @navbarLinkColorActive;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: @navbarLinkBackgroundActive;
  .box-shadow(inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.125));
}
```

Now, the 'problem' is that my 'li' does not have the class `.active`, but `.current-menu-item`. But I still want to apply the above CSS to the `a` element. So in my own `style.less` file, I added:

```
li.current-menu-item a {
  .navbar .nav > .active > a;
}
```

But for some reason this is not working. I'm not able to figure out why it is not working. To illustrate, I want to give a example that IS working.

In Twitter Bootstrap v. 2.3.2 you can find `type.less` that has the following code:

```
// Single-line list items
ul.inline,
ol.inline {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  > li {
    display: inline-block;
    .ie7-inline-block();
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

For horizontal menu, where in the source code my `ul` element does not have a class `.inline`, but `.menu`, I simply do this in my own `style.less`:

```
ul.menu {
   ul.inline;
}
```

That is working with NO problems at all. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

afaik, your

```
ul.menu {
   ul.inline;
}
```

code does not work too.

Your problem seems very similar to [Overwriting Twitter Bootstrap Less not working, adding new things does work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692134/overwriting-twitter-bootstrap-less-not-working-adding-new-things-does-work)

You can only mixin simple classes.

Try the following Less code:

```
li.current-menu-item a {
  &:extend(.navbar .nav > .active > a);
}
```

Also see: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-combining-styles-a-more-advanced-mixin